# convert an object to a System.Data DataTable

Tags: c#, generics, optimization, polymorphism

as i am a last step away from accomplishing  my task i got little stuck.

the  task is to achieve an all around solution to populate any fetched `DataTable` From Sql Db (without the use of the .NET ORM or any ready solution)

the structure is basic as it could be, a class that represents the `C#` code that will accommodate the SQL Server Table, and the corresponding method that will populate the fetched table.

this should be simple task if i knew the how-to of inheritance properly,
which is what i am learning about through this implementation.

so thanks for taking the time to try and help solve this issue !

what i have done so far is almost Complete :

- `DbTblmetaM` is the setting type contains the key info to fetch Db Table
- `ColumnDefA` is the Columns Definition, which is the base of table

and the last

- `ColA` is a Basic Column model (intCol, strCol, dateCol, etc')

the method looks like this :

```
public static DataTable ToDataTableTest(this DbSchema.SqlServerTables.ColumnDefA Self)
{
                // v--returns a cloned schema DataTable
    var RtDtt = GetSchemaViaDa(Self.CdefTable.Catalog, Self.CdefTable.Name);

     //use an easy expensive reflection ? 
     //or a the unknown For-loop on each TableObject.ColumnObject.itemsList "Vals"
    return;
}
```

and the problem i am facing is that i could not figure the way i should structure the object Base class so the method will * just need to loop through its columns object to populate any given Server table.

*given the fact that every object is properly set to follow the structure of its Server Table accordingly

**what am i missing here ?**

**UPDATE**

the core of my problem :

```
var someColumn1 = (Self as CdfHddFoldersFiles).FileId;
```

in the method above, this is the only way i can now access any server table columns (table-Objects fields).

but as it has to be for any table meaning 
i could have `cdfSomeOthertable:ColumnDefA` that i will need to specify the type for every object, that's exactly my problem for now.

thanks.

```
//the setting type contains the key info to fetch Db Table
public class DbTablemetaM
{
    public string Catalog { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public virtual string IdenttCol { get; private set; }
    public DbTablemetaM(string bsCatalog, string bsName, string bsIdentCol)
    {
        this.Catalog = bsCatalog;
        this.Name = bsName;
        this.IdenttCol= bsIdentCol;
    }
}
public class ColumnDefA
{
    public virtual DbTablemetaM CdefTable { get; set; }
}
public class CdfHddFoldersFiles : ColumnDefA
{
    public override DbTablemetaM CdefTable
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CdefTable;
        }
        set
        {
            base.CdefTable = value;
        }
    }
    public ColsI.IntC FileId, FileSize;
    public ColsI.StrC CurFileName, DriveL, FilePath, FileExt;

    public ColsI.DateC Created;
    public CdfHddFoldersFiles()
    {
    }
}

public class ColA
{
    public virtual Type DataType { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<object> Vals { get; set; }
    public ColA()
    {
       this.Vals = new List<object>();
    }
}

public class ColsI
{
    public class StrC : ColA
    {
        public new String DataType;
        public new List<String> Vals { get; set; }
        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Name;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Name = value;
            }
        }
        public StrC()
        {
            this.Vals = new List<String>();
        }
    }

}
```

2nd Update:

adding required method into the table object class as a member is my workaround
i can now accomplish the task of creating data suitable for given table, 
clone schema to `DataTable`, then :

by adding another member as DataTable, and method member to execute

```
public override void fetchAndPopulateServerTable()
{
    this.DttToPush = this.Row.ToDataTableTest();

    var RowsFileId = this.Row.FileId.Vals;
    var RowsCurFileName = this.Row.CurFileName.Vals;
    var RowsDriveL = this.Row.DriveL.Vals;
    var RowsFilePath = this.Row.FilePath.Vals;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.Row.FileId.Vals.Count; i++)
    {
        var Nwdr = this.DttToPush.NewRow();
        Nwdr[this.Row.FileId.Name] = RowsFileId[i];
        Nwdr[this.Row.CurFileName.Name] =RowsCurFileName[i];
        Nwdr[this.Row.DriveL.Name] = RowsDriveL[i];
        Nwdr[this.Row.FilePath.Name] = RowsFilePath[i];


        this.DttToPush.Rows.Add(Nwdr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use typed datasets instead? Having your own definition of the db schema would be just reinventing the wheel. Or just build wrappers around `DataRow`, `DataTable` and `DataSet`.